# Replace tag inbetween parentheses in eps with psfrag/chemnum

Tags: psfrag, chemnum

### Question

Is it possible to replace the `TMP1` inbetween some parentheses (or other symbols and text) with chemnum?

### Examples

The following shows the input (*eps*; left), and the output (*compiled file*; right):

[image]

Maybe also used like this, as often seen in journals:

[image]

Comment: If it works with `psfrag` then it works with `chemnum`. So the question rather is: is it possible with `psfrag` to replace a substring in a postscript or EPS file?

Comment: I don't think substring replacements are possible with `psfrag`. Why not just replace the whole string, brackets included (i.e. `\psfrag{(TMP1)}{(1)}` and likewise for the second case)?

Comment: @Ian: Someone could than maybe use `replacecmpd{...}` (`chemnum`), to replace the isolated `TMP1` through a number, and then use `psfrag` to replace the obtained substituted string. The only problem is, that you never really know, which number will be in there (since there might be compounds added before in the work of progress)

I will give it a try - maybe it can be done with
`\replacecmpd{\cmpd{CAS:532-27-4}}` and a consecutive `\psfrag{\cmpd{CAS:532-27-4}}{(\cmpd{CAS:532-27-4})}`, if there is the isolated `TMP1` in the eps.

I will post the results of this experiment later on.

Comment: @lcnittl `\replacecmpd{foo}` internally at some time does the equivalent of `\psfrag{TMP1}{\cmpd{foo}}`. (`\replacecmpd{\cmpd{CAS:532-27-4}}` will *certainly* not work...)

Comment: @cgnieder You were totally right - It didn't work. But I came up with another solution - Not really nice, and everything else than automatic, but at least a workaround: `{\psfrag{(TMP1)}{(\cmpd{a})}\includegraphics{./test.eps}}` (so an adopted version of what `chemnum` does)

Comment: You can try `\replacecmpd[tag=(TMP1)]{a}` instead of `\psfrag{(TMP1)}{(\cmpd{a})}`.

Comment: @cgnieder `\replacecmpd[tag=(TMP1)]{a}` will unfortunately not keep the parentheses around the compound number.
To answer the question whether it's possible to replace _substrings_ with `psfrag`, and therefore also with `chemnum`: I just found the answer in `psfrag`s [manual](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf) (page 10 at the very bottom): **No**, sadly

Comment: Oh yes, you're right... I forgot about the parentheses in the output.

Comment: @cgnieder no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The *pure* answer

It doen't seem to be possibly in a native way, since `psfrag` (used by `chemnum` to replace the tags) is not supporting this kind of replacements, as can be read in the [`psfrag` manual](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf) (page 10 at the very bottom), where it says:

> And PSfrag can only replace entire strings, not just parts of one. So if your EPS file contains
>
> ```
> (I want to replace the XXX here) show
> ```
>
> then the `\psfrag` command will fail if you supply just the XXX.

### Approaches to still acquire the replacement

For the purpose of the following examples, this main code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemstyle} %Needed for scheme environment

\begin{document}    
  \input{code}
\end{document}
```

applies, where `\input{code}` would insert the code snippets from below.

The used graphic (`EPS.eps`) can be *any* `.eps` file containing the phrase `(TMS1)`.
**Note:** Of course also `TMP1` instead of `(TMP1)` will work, thus there's the danger, that this tag gets automatically substituted by `chemnum` (as this is the standard tag, and the normally desired behaviour), if one is not working carefully.

#### A silver lining

Altough, I came up with a small workaround to *solve* this problem. I have to admit, that this solution is not really considered to be beautiful, but as there's no other solution (or at least I couldn't find one), someone in the need of this replacement has to accept to work with it.

The code

```
\psfrag{(TMP1)}{(\cmpd{a})}
\includegraphics{./EPS.eps}
```

does the job. This is an adoption of what `\replacecmpd{foo}` of `chemnum` is doing at some point.

This could also be packed inside a `figure` or `scheme` (as provided by `chemstyle` package) environment

```
\begin{scheme}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \psfrag{(TMP1)}{(\cmpd{a})}
  \includegraphics{./EPS.eps}
  \label{schm:label}
\end{scheme}
```

what I believe would be the standard usage.

#### A failed approach

I also tried to use

```
\begin{scheme}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \psfrag{\cmpd+{a}}{(\cmpd+{a})}
  \includegraphics{
    \replacecmpd[tag=(TMP1)]{a}
    \includegraphics{./chemnum_question.eps}
  }
  \label{schm:label}
\end{scheme}
```

to make a double replacement (`(TMP1)` > `1` *(in this example)* and in a second step `1` > `(1)`). The nested `\includegraphics` command is used in [`psfrag` manual](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf) (page 9 in the middle), where:

> \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{\includegraphics{example.eps}}

is used to scale the image *and* the replaced strings.

But using this technique failes, as it entails an error (`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`).