# How to use chemnum with chemdraw in xepersian?

Tags: shell-escape, xepersian, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

Pay attention to the first code that represents the numbering of molecules in a scheme that is imported into LaTeX from the ".eps" file and by the command

> pdflatex -shell-escape file1.tex

runs without any problems.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{CyAZIDES.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:4}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{CyAZIDES2.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The second code that was created using xepersian and by command

> xelatex --shell-escape file2.tex

has been created that does not replace numbers correctly.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Zar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{CyAZIDES.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:4}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{CyAZIDES2.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please attach CyAZIDES2.eps and CyAZIDES.eps.

Comment: Excuse me! would you help me how to upload "CyAZIDES.eps" and "CyAZIDES2.eps" files?

Comment: Excuse me. I thought this site has this ability.
You can send them to me if you want. (See my profile)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the `xepersian` package. I think (but I am not sure) this problem related to `xelatex compiler` (at least in texstudio for me). I saw this problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182785/replace-tag-inbetween-parentheses-in-eps-with-psfrag-chemnum/182957) and other place too.
even without xepersian package you get this problem.
I find a trick for solve it. open 0-2.eps with notepad++ and change it as the below:

[image]
So your codes will change to this structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[localise,Kashida,computeautoilg]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=4.4]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{latin}\centering
        Test
    \end{latin}
    \begin{latin}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{0-2.eps}
        \end{figure}
    \end{latin}
\end{document}
```

Where your compiler set as the below:

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Otput:

[image]
Good luck.

Comment: It is a "tricky trick" for solving this problem! The aim of label replacement is dynamic numbering of chemical compounds in latex run-time. Otherwise, the numbering of these compounds in chemdraw is much more easier than this tricks.