# chemnum - expand the replaced label by a few characters

Tags: chemnum, number

I would like to label a compound like this, in my chemdraw file:
[image]

Can chemnum replace the TMP in an .eps-file with **1a**: M = Ti, n = 2 for example? [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182785/220499) is a similar question, but i would like to expand the replacement by a few characters.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareNewTOC[
type=scheme,
types=schemes,
float,
name=Schema,
listname={Verzeichnis der Schemata}
]{los}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{format = \bfseries\sffamily}


\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\replacecmpd{mycompund.a}
\replacecmpd{mycompund.b}
\replacecmpd{mycompund.c}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{xyz}
\caption{My compounds.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}
Compound \refcmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `\psfrag` command from the `psfrag` package, which in turn is loaded by `chemnum` you can replace any placeholder text in an `.eps` file with any other LaTeX command or text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareNewTOC[
type=scheme,
types=schemes,
float,
name=Schema,
listname={Verzeichnis der Schemata}
]{los}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{format = \bfseries\sffamily}


\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\psfrag{TMP1}{\cmpd{mycompound.a}: M = Ti, n = 4}
\psfrag{TMP2}{\cmpd{mycompound.b}: M = Fe, n = 3}
\psfrag{TMP3}{\cmpd{mycompound.c}: M = Sn, n = 4}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{My compounds. The replacement text is left aligned with respect to the placeholder text.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\psfrag{TMP1}[c][l]{\cmpd{mycompound.a}: M = Ti, n = 4}
\psfrag{TMP2}[c][l]{\cmpd{mycompound.b}: M = Fe, n = 3}
\psfrag{TMP3}[c][l]{\cmpd{mycompound.c}: M = Sn, n = 4}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{My compounds. The replacement text is horizontally centered with respect to the placeholder text.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}


Compound \cmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is looking good.

Comment: When i combine your example with another scheme, i get wrong numbering in text. I asked a follow up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557917/220499)