# chemnum - wrong numbering in text

Tags: psfrag, chemnum, number

This is a follow up question to this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557820%60%60).
I am getting trouble with the numbering in text, when i combine the first scheme with a second scheme. If i include the text at position one, the numbering is correct. When i add the text after the second scheme, i get wrong numbers in text.

only position 1:

[image]

only position 2:

[image]

I thought i will get the same numbers at the second position as at position one. What went wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareNewTOC[
type=scheme,
types=schemes,
float,
name=Schema,
listname={Verzeichnis der Schemata}
]{los}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum} 
\setchemnum{format = \bfseries\sffamily}


\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\psfrag{TMP1}{\cmpd{mycompound.a}: M = Ti, n = 4}
\psfrag{TMP2}{\cmpd{mycompound.b}: M = Fe, n = 3}
\psfrag{TMP3}{\cmpd{mycompound.c}: M = Sn, n = 4}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{My compounds. The replacement text is left aligned with respect to the placeholder text.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}
%position1
%Compound \cmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.
\clearpage
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\replacecmpd{one}
\replacecmpd{two}
\replacecmpd{three}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{second scheme}
\label{mycompounds2}
\end{scheme}
\cmpd{one, two, three}

%position2
Compound \cmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, adding `\cmpd*{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c}` right before the first `\psfrag` should result in correct numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `\cmpd` inside of `psfrag` apparently messes up the initiation/definition of the corresponding compounds. You can prevent that by defining the new label yourself using `\cmpd*{<ID>}` inside of the `scheme` environment, for example as follows:

```
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\cmpd*{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c}
\psfrag{TMP1}{\cmpd{mycompound.a}: M = Ti, n = 4}
\psfrag{TMP2}{\cmpd{mycompound.b}: M = Fe, n = 3}
\psfrag{TMP3}{\cmpd{mycompound.c}: M = Sn, n = 4}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{My compounds. The replacement text is left aligned with respect to the placeholder text.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}
```

In order to avoid typing the same ID twice and to avoid accidentally messing up the order of the IDs, you can also define your own command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\replacecmpdcomment}[3]{\cmpd*{#2}\psfrag{#1}{\cmpd{#2}: #3}}
```

You can then use it in your document as follows:

```
\replacecmpdcomment{<replacement tag>}{<compound's ID>}{<comment to be added>}
```

Full example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareNewTOC[
type=scheme,
types=schemes,
float,
name=Schema,
listname={Verzeichnis der Schemata}
]{los}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum} 
\setchemnum{format = \bfseries\sffamily}

\newcommand{\replacecmpdcomment}[3]{\cmpd*{#2}\psfrag{#1}{\cmpd{#2}: #3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\replacecmpdcomment{TMP1}{mycompound.a}{M = Ti, n = 4}
\replacecmpdcomment{TMP2}{mycompound.b}{M = Fe, n = 3}
\replacecmpdcomment{TMP3}{mycompound.c}{M = Sn, n = 4}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{My compounds. The replacement text is left aligned with respect to the placeholder text.}
\label{mycompounds}
\end{scheme}
%position1
%Compound \cmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.
\clearpage
\begin{scheme}[htb]
\centering
\replacecmpd{one}
\replacecmpd{two}
\replacecmpd{three}
\includegraphics{xyz}
\caption{second scheme}
\label{mycompounds2}
\end{scheme}
\cmpd{one, two, three}

%position2
Compound \cmpd{mycompound.a, mycompound.b, mycompound.c} are my compounds.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This reminds me of https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues/6

Comment: @leandriis: Thank you very much again.

Comment: @leandriis: The first image in your answer did not show the result. [This](https://imgur.com/a/gwy5DK9) is what i get (and wanted to get).

Comment: @cgnieder: That's definitely related. I didn't know using the +-version inside of `\psfrag` could cause problems. @solstafir: Good catch. The original screenshot was created using an `.eps` file with a too small bounding box, hence the text got cut off. I have corrected that in my answer.